# Union function for worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that loops through my worksheets and flags them by colouring their tab red and adds their sheet name to a string. When the loop is done, a message box is displayed with a message listing the sheet name string and asking if all listed sheets should be deleted.

My next step was going to be to repeat the code for the loop and this time instead of colouring and adding the name to a string, I was going to .delete the sheet.

#### Is there a way to build a selection set while going through the loop the first time so that if delete is option is selected I can do something similar to selection.delete?

```
Sub Audit_Estimate_sheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws_List As String
    Dim Delete_Orphans As Integer
    Dim Item_List_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Item_List_First_Row As Long
    Dim Item_List_Max_Row As Long
    
    Set Item_List_Sheet = Sheets(2)
        
    Item_List_First_Row = 14
    Item_List_Max_Row = Item_List_First_Row + Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Item_List_Sheet.Range("B:B")) - 1
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Item_List_Sheet.Range("C" & Item_List_First_Row & ":C" & Item_List_Max_Row), 0)) And Not exception(ws.CodeName) Then
            'Colour Tab'
            With ws.Tab
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            'Add name to list
            If ws_List = "" Then
                ws_List = ws.Name
            Else
                ws_List = ws_List & ", " & ws.Name
            End If
        'SELECTION_SET = UNION(SELECTION_SET, ws)
        End If
    Next ws
    
    'display list
    Delete_Orphans = MsgBox("The following estimate sheets were not part of the item list and are currently orphaned:  " & vbLf & vbLf & ws_List & vbLf & vbLf & "Would you like to delete them?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Orphaned Estimates")
        
    If Delete_Orphans = vbYes Then
        'loop through sheets again and delete

        'avoid looping again. build selection set in first loop
        'then delete section.
    End If

End Sub
```

I looked at the [UNION FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) but if I understand correctly it is used for ranges not worksheets.

#### Is there a better way to achieve what I am describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to loop again but this way the loop will occur only within the sheets you need to delete:

```
Sub Audit_Estimate_sheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws_List As String
    Dim Delete_Orphans As Integer
    Dim Item_List_Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Item_List_First_Row As Long
    Dim Item_List_Max_Row As Long

    Set Item_List_Sheet = Sheets(2)

    Item_List_First_Row = 14
    Item_List_Max_Row = Item_List_First_Row + Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Item_List_Sheet.Range("B:B")) - 1

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Item_List_Sheet.Range("C" & Item_List_First_Row & ":C" & Item_List_Max_Row), 0)) And Not exception(ws.CodeName) Then
            'Colour Tab'
            With ws.Tab
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            'Add name to list
            If ws_List = "" Then
                ws_List = ws.Name
            Else
                ws_List = ws_List & ", " & ws.Name
            End If
        'SELECTION_SET = UNION(SELECTION_SET, ws)
        End If
    Next ws

    'display list
    Delete_Orphans = MsgBox("The following estimate sheets were not part of the item list and are currently orphaned:  " & vbLf & vbLf & ws_List & vbLf & vbLf & "Would you like to delete them?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Orphaned Estimates")

    Dim SplitSheets As Variant 'Declare an Array type variable
    Dim i As Integer

    If Delete_Orphans = vbYes Then
        'loop through sheets again and delete
        SplitSheets = Split(ws_List, ", ") 'here you will split all the names into one array
        For i = LBound(SplitSheets) To UBound(SplitSheets) 'this way you will loop, but only on the sheets you need to.
            wb.Sheets(SplitSheets(i)).Delete
        Next i
        'avoid looping again. build selection set in first loop
        'then delete section.
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I was not aware of SPLIT.  I like it as it is reusing what I had done earlier.  While awaiting for insight on potential union, I had thought of building an array of sheet names in the first loop, but I am liking the simplicity of this approach.